# Google Analytics — character limit on Filter Pattern field

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, spam, spam-prevention, google-analytics-spam

It took me a while but I finally found out how to use filters to block spam from my analytics.

I currently have the following filter pattern applied to 'campaign source'

```
semalt\.com|buttons-for-website\.com|rank-checker\.online|monetizationking\.net|site-auditor\.online|topbestlisted\.com|site-speed-check\.site|site-speed-checker\.site|scanner-elena\.top|scanner-mary\.top|scanner-irvin\.top|scanner-jack\.top
```

I've just noticed a couple of new spam bots that have recently showed up under my Referrals section, but now it won't let me add any more to the filter pattern due to the character limit.

What is the best solution to get around it? Do I just have to set up an additional filter?

Comment: Is using the \.com parts necessary? Can't you just use something like semalt|buttons-for-website|rank-checker|etc etc

Comment: @James perhaps, but even then there would still be the unnecessarily strict character limit... I just had to create an additional filter in the end. Thanks anyway though!

Answer (score 1):

Since these are exclude filters, you can create multiple filters that include referrer names up to the character limit. This is how I do it.